Republish native libs to the old location
I am working on a large C++ project and we are also building for Android. Recently we decided to update AGP to the latest version (8.7.2). We also have a bunch of python scripts to process our native libraries after the build. These scripts expect to find the libraries in a predefined location which looks like build/intermediates/cmake/debug/...
This scheme worked fine with AGP 7.4, but it broke with the update. AGP no longer stores native build outputs in build/intermediates/cmake/debug/...
Looking for a solution I glanced over AGP source code and found some mysterious variable called NDK_SO_REPUBLISH_DIR:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/mirror-goog-studio-main/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/cxx/settings/MacroDefinitions.kt#365
The comment following the variable says:
A folder with a predictable name where final build outputs (mainly .so) are hard linked or copied after the build completes. The purpose is so scripts and other external tools have a known path, with no embedded hashcode, to locate these files.
It seems like an internal thing, but if not it is still unclear how am I supposed to use it. I have also found a commit which introduced a republishing behaviour:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/9e175de84fa6e0d706101e35632d0c031f1bc6c7
But it does not seem to work. Perhaps it should be explicitly configured. Or I misunderstand something. So I was wondering if there is a way to republish native build artifacts to the old location.
Any help would be appreciated.
The viable solution is to manually copy these libs from merged_native_libs${Configuration}\merge${Configuration}NativeLibs\out\lib, but it is not ideal.

Doing this postprocessing in CMake sounds less prone to breakage. I suppose that will not work due to some other reason?
